# Python advanced deleting text in a column

Tags: python, string, editing

Hello everyone I have a database that kicks out song names with the folders and was wondering if there was a way that a python script could delete some of the text.

My data:

```
https://location.com/loaction/folder1/album/songname.mp3
https://location.com/loaction2/folder2/album/songname1.mp3
https://location.com/loaction3/folder3/album/songname2.mp3
https://location.com/loaction4/folder4/album/songname3.mp3
https://location.com/loaction5/folder5/album/songname4.mp3
```

and was wondering if there was a way to get it to look like this.

```
songname.mp3
songname1.mp3
songname2.mp3
songname3.mp3
songname4.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> 'https://location.com/loaction2/folder2/album/songname1.mp3'.rsplit('/', 1)
['https://location.com/loaction2/folder2/album', 'songname1.mp3']

>>> 'https://location.com/loaction2/folder2/album/songname1.mp3'.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
'songname1.mp3'
```

Comment: would that do that for the rest of the database or would i have to specify the folders.

Comment: @chrismayer, I assumed the each line represents each record.

Comment: @chrismayer, What do you mean `the rest of database`?

Comment: Like each album name would have to be purt into the script or can I do a thing that counts the / if 17000 records all with different album names

Comment: @chrismayer, Iterate each record, and apply above code for the record. `for record in records: print(record.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])`